# Solve equation with two unknowns

Tags: trigonometry

I have these equations.

$2\pi r_1+2\pi r_2=24$

and $\pi r_1^2+\pi r_2^2=20$

and to solve them I did the following steps

Step 1 : $\frac {2\pi r_1+2\pi r_2}{2}= \frac {24}{2}$

Step 2 : $\pi r_1+\pi r_2= 12$

Step 3 : $\pi r_1= 12 - \pi r_2$

Step 4 : $\pi r_1^2+(12 - \pi r_2)^2=20$

Step 5 : $\pi r_1^2+(12 - \pi r_2)^2=20$

Step 6 : $\pi r_1^2+144 - 24\pi r_2 + \pi r_1^2=20$

Step 7 : $2\pi r_1^2- 24\pi r_2+124=0$

Step 8 : $\pi r_1 = - \frac {-24}{2} \pm \sqrt{(\frac {-24}{2})^2 - 124}$

I get the result $6 \pm \sqrt{10}$ but is this correct? Something feels wrong about this answer but don't know what.

Thanks!

Comment: You can always substitute the solution into the equations to check if they're valid.

Comment: There is no need to go on what "feels" wrong. Plug the values in the equations and see if they hold. If not, the value is wrong.

Comment: Step 4 is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{cases}2\pi r_1+2\pi r_2=24 & (1) \\ \pi r_1^2+\pi r_2^2=20 & (2)\end{cases}$

Equation $(1)$ gives $r_1=\frac{12-\pi r_2}{\pi}$

Plug that into $(2)$, we have $\pi\big(\frac{12-\pi r_2}{\pi}\big)^2+\pi r_2^2=20 \Rightarrow 2\pi r_2^2-24r_2+\frac{144}{\pi}-20=0$.

This quadratic equation has no solutions, and therefore there is no solution to the system of equations.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Step 3 you have  $\pi r_1 = 12 - \pi r_2$ and in Step 4 you wrongly plugged $\pi r_{1}$ into $\pi r_{2}^{2}$,
$\pi r_1 != \pi r_{2}^2  $ furthermore $\pi r_1^2 != (\pi r_1)^2$

Answer (score 0):

Step 4 is the issue. You replaced $r_2$ with $\pi r_1$.

Solving for $r_1 = \frac{12}{\pi} - r_2$ and replacing into the second equation, ($r_1^2 + r_2 = \frac{20}{\pi}$) you'll get a solution for $r_2$. Plugging this value into your first equation will give you slution for $r_2$.